# TYPO3 error with scheduler task - "Task failed to execute successfully"

Tags: typo3, scheduler, typo3-10.x

TYPO3 using TYPO3 10.4.21 with extensions (pizpalue and calendarize).
Application context is Development.

I made some appointments with the extension calendarize (Ver.11.0.1). And then,
I added a new task in scheduler/planer:

- class: execute console commands
- Type: Recurring
- Frequency: 0 */2 * * *
- Schedulable Command: calendarize:imports a iCalendar ICS into a page ID
- Argument icsCalendarUri.The URI of the iCalendar ICS: ics-file of outlook.office365.com
- Argument pid: 65

There is still a error message:

If the above task had run in scheduler, an error comes up:
I don't know if the task and a below error are related each other, but I note it for sure. The date, when the error in error log came up, is before the scheduled task had run.

```
Execution of task "Execute console commands (scheduler)" failed with the following message: Task failed to execute successfully. Class: TYPO3\CMS\Scheduler\Task\ExecuteSchedulableCommandTask, UID: 1
```

I checked out a error log in /typo3temp/var/log, there is an error:

```
Mon, 11 Oct 2021 13:24:15 +0200 [WARNING] request="b09a9abc4780f" component="TYPO3.CMS.Extensionmanager.Utility.InstallUtility": Imported site configuration with identifier default could not be mapped to imported page id
```

I don't know how I fix it at all. Which file (+ folder), which code and how etc. ...

I'm an internship student and I have just a few experience with TYPO3 (for a few weeks).

Unfortunately I couldn't find some answer in the internet for my problems. (I don't use Extension of Instagram in TYPO3)

I hope someone explain me what I should do in detail to fix these problems.

Thank you for reading this and your help.

Comment: Please tell us about the task you are running, not sure if your exception is related to the task failure at all.

Comment: @Simon Gilli
Thank you for your asking. I added some information about the task in the main text. I hope you can understand with my text.....

Comment: The error points to a problem to resolve a `Site` for a given page. Is your page 65 inside a `Site` if you look at it in the page tree in the module "List"?

Comment: @Jonas Eberle
The page id 65 is a folder of appointment, in which some events are there. So id 65 is not a page, but a folder for an appointment in my tree in the module List....

Comment: Can confirm the failure is not related to the error log. Do you get an exception in the backend if you manually run the task there?

Comment: @Simon Gilli
Thank you, then I ignore the error log for now. And the message "Task failed to execute successfully" in ExecuteSchedulableCommandTask comes up, if I pushed a button "run task" of the uid=1. But is it in the frontend? I'm sorry I don't know how I run the task in the backend...

Comment: No, that's the backend. In TYPO3 language the backend is everything under /typo3. 

Next step here is to make the logging more verbose, first try to set the env var TYPO3_CONTEXT=development.

BTW the other error is related to a missing siteconfiguration here https://github.com/buepro/typo3-pizpalue/tree/master/Initialisation. Maybe you file an issue at the extension therefor. A working example can be found here https://github.com/FriendsOfTYPO3/introduction/tree/master/Initialisation/Site/introduction.

Comment: @Simon Gilli
"SetEnv TYPO3_CONTEXT Development" should be written in .htaccess-file, right? There are a few htaccess-files in /typo3_src-10.4.21/typo3/sysext/install/Resources/Private/FolderStructureTemplateFiles. I found a text "TYPO3_CONTEXT:Development" in the root-htaccess-file. Maybe, should I change the application context from Production to Development? (now Production)
I have now a problem with the htaccess-file and where I write the text down...

Comment: Yes, you can provide this variable with the .htaccess in case of Apache.

Comment: @Simon Gilli
I wrote "SetEnv TYPO3_CONTEXT Development" in .htaccess, but there is still an error message, when I run the task. Do I have to change something more?

Comment: Anyway, because the application context wasn't changed from production to development, I wrote the following code in index.php in addition. Now the application context is "Development".
```if($_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] == 'example.com') {
   putenv('TYPO3_CONTEXT=Development'); }```

Comment: Is there anyone who can answer my question?
I'm still in trouble with the error. I'd changed the application context to "development", but there is still a error message. Do I have to change anything in a file or setting?

Comment: Now in the development context you should run the command again in the backend and the check all TYPO3 error logs again for new hints about the reason of the failure.

Comment: @Simon Gilli
 Thank you for your help. Okay, I'll figure out some errors at first. Thank you.